# Run elasticdump (Node executable) in a AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, bash, aws-lambda

I wish to run the `elasticdump` command within an AWS Lambda function. This package is installed via NPM and then run on the CLI (https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump).

The way I approached this was to run a bash script within the Node script. I installed into `elasticdump` into the `node_modules` folder which I then uploaded as a .zip to AWS Lambda.

Here is the Node script itself which calls the bash script executable:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
    execFile('./run-elasticdump.sh', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            callback(error);
        }
        callback(null, stdout);
    });
}
```

The bash script itself attempts to run the `elasticdump` command which again is within the `node_modules` folder:

```
run-elasticdump.sh

elasticdump \
  --input=http://es.com:9200/template-filter \
  --output=templates.json \
  --type=template
```

Here is the folder structure:

```
run-elasticdump
- node_modules
-- elasticdump
-- ...
- package.json
- index.js
- run-elasticdump.sh
```

When I run the lambda, I receive the following error:

```
    "elasticdump: command not found",
    "",
    "    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)",
    "    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)",
    "    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)",
    "    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:439:11)",
    "    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)",
    "    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12)"
  ]
```

I believe this is because the `elasticdump` package installed within the `node_modules` folder is not being recognised at bash runtime.

Any ideas or suggestions of how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have already uploaded `node_modules` you just need to run the proper elasticdump script at the proper location. The working one is `./node_modules/elasticdump/bin/elasticdump`.

Note there's another location where you may find the script `./node_modules/.bin/elasticdump` but this one will not work due to dependencies' location errors.